# What happened to the 30 day job credits?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Why is the option to buy job credits for 30 days gone?

This has only happened recently because we took a screenshot last showing that the option was there. We got finance approved for two listings for 30 days each, but now we can't actually buy 30 days worth of credits. It's not in [the listings](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/checkout/listing/choose) any more.

[image: Screenshot last week]

But now we can only purchase 90 days worth of credits. What happened?

Comment: Jesus, how much?!

Comment: @Lightness someone needs to pay for all the servers :P

Comment: @simbabque: I suppose unicorn food ain't cheap either

Comment: And maintaining the server that hosts "Jon Skeet"'s artificial consciousness is likely to be costly

Comment: The annual one is a real bargain.

Comment: the screen real estate on the site is precioussss

Comment: @JamesENL Are these prices available to everyone? Can you please add a link to this table if possible?

Comment: @A.L If you have an account on careers.stackoverflow.com you can go here: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/checkout/listing/choose to see [this](http://i.imgur.com/26ZLUhf.png) current table. The one OP posted was the one he sent to finance to get it approved, but now [most of the options are not there any more](http://i.imgur.com/26ZLUhf.png).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks, I added the link in the question, it's available for everyone, I was able to see it in an private mode window.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the amount of money depends on where the job is located. It's even more expensive in Germany (2990€ = 3385 USD)

Comment: It's weird that they don't have country tiers...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the pricing system - there has *got* to be something wrong with a job you have to advertise for a year. (But then I suppose you can advertise multiple positions...)

Comment: @Pekka웃 you'd be surprised how hard it is to hire senior engineers in places like Stockholm, Sweden. Took us two years to hire a test lead once.

Comment: @Claus fair enough...

Comment: @ClausJørgensen does that have to do with the shortage of places to live?

Comment: It can easily cost $10k to go through the process to hire a qualified engineer.  Anybody who has gone through the process before is probably aware the cost of listing a job and the value tradeoff.

Comment: I understand that countries would be different, but why is UK 26% more than the normal price and Germany 66% more? Wow

Comment: Also, why can I say I want to hire developers from Antarctica? Is that an emerging market we need to be cautious of?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen It is never hard if you pay enough. ;)

Comment: @Gendarme Even if you pay enough, you need a funnel of applicants, and a way to find a qualified candidate, first.  That can be hard, even if you are paying the moon.

Comment: @JamesENL probably lots of qualified *Reichsdeutsche* residing in Hitler's base underneath Antarctica. They're some 20 years behind, so the big IT wave is just starting for them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We found that often 30 days just isn't enough time to make a hire, and that in offering this option we weren't really setting our clients up for success (the same goes for the 60 day option). It just wasn't that great a product, and one that could set unrealistic expectations and then lead to disappointment and/or greater costs by then having to extend the post with another 30 days. We decided we much rather offer only those products that we feel will allow our clients a greater chance of success.

PS: All our longer term listing products will allow you to swap out jobs, so you can always post a new position once you've found someone for your current opening.